# Function call creates contract?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I am using a NodeJS backend to call a payable smart contract function. The simple function, however, are running out of gas on Rinkeby when I give the max possible. It should be calling a function, but instead it is creating a contract. Why is this?

**Main code:**

```
var privateKey = '..'
var nodeWalletAddress = '..' // Backend's Wallet address
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
var gas = 7000000;
let method = contract.methods.myMethod(params);
  var encodedABI = method.encodeABI();
  var tx = {
    from: nodeWalletAddress,
    to: contract.address,
    gas: gas,
    gasPrice: 1000000000,
    data: encodedABI
  };

 signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
```

**signTransaction function:**

```
function signTransaction(tx, privateKey) {
    log('Singing transaction..')
    web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
        var tran = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);

        tran.on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
          console.log('confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
        });

        tran.on('transactionHash', hash => {
          console.log('hash');
          console.log(hash);
        });

        tran.on('receipt', receipt => {
          console.log('reciept');
          console.log(receipt);
        });

         tran.on('error', error => {
            console.log('txError')
            console.log(error)
        });
      });
}
```

**Log**

```
Singing transaction..
hash
0xfea700ce60035e3d06eadb7135d8fde74d0dac43f04061031e0c3228e0dd38ea
confirmation: 0
txError
Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:
{
  "blockHash": "0xd77f1b383625f9e2deb56ffa257d56f877f2fb58637230ec6b129ca08687fae5",
  "blockNumber": 2768086,
  "contractAddress": "0xccEAc5bC12777038793351DA67B1730bCb368b93",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 7090940,
  "from": "0x40b046d0563c498e5b13414ba9e41ed60291f5b9",
  "gasUsed": 7000000,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": null,
  "transactionHash": "0xfea700ce60035e3d06eadb7135d8fde74d0dac43f04061031e0c3228e0dd38ea",
  "transactionIndex": 3
}
```

**Note:**
The contract function is fairly simple and shouldn't use anything
remotely close to 700,000 WEI gas.

It is creating a contract, but the hash it is creating is showing `[contract creation` in the To address

Comment: why are you setting your gas price so high 1000000000

Comment: @johnny5 rinkeby gas price standard is usually 1 GWEI I believe

Comment: are you sure it looks lie you may have some extra 0's there, eg your gas price is way higher than your total gas

Comment: @johnny5 Double checking now, but regardless though it is *running out* of gas, so additional gas anywhere wouldn't be an issue

Comment: Ok I am sure that gas price is correct.

Comment: do you see that the gas is being consumed, after you run the transaction, are you sure it's not getting rejected immediately?